# insert statement using request and session

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

for some reason I cant seem to get the data to insert php and mysql.

I have a `init.php` with the connection string in, a `order.ph`p file and finaly a `band_list.php`.
I am having some problem getting the data in to database.

the database has 3 tables:

`order it has id, order_id and band_id columns`

`users it has id, name and password columns`

`bands it has Band_id, name and stock columns`

**band_list.php has a band gig details in it shown to the user.**

```
    <?php
require 'core/init.php';
    $Band_id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bands WHERE Band_id = $Band_id");

    echo "<table border = '1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Band Name</th>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Add</th>
    </tr>";

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr><form name=\"myform\" action=\" order.php\"  method=\"post\">";
           echo "<td> <input name=\"band\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"". $Band_id."\" ></td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Venue']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Category']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Stock']. "</td>";
            echo "<td><button>Buy Ticket</button></td>";
            echo "<td><input type=\" submit\" value=\"Buy Ticket\"></td>";
            echo "</tr> </form>";
        }

    echo "</table>";


    ?>
```

**order.php has the query that is meant to send the data to the database**

```
    <?php
require 'core/init.php';

session_start();
$Band_id = $_REQUEST['Band_id'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (band_id,user_id) VALUES($Band_id,$user_id)";
mysql_query ($sql, $linkme)
    or die ("could not add to database");
?>
```

and the connection string is in a init file.

so the idea is when the user clicks buy ticket it gets the current `Band_id` and `user_id` and inserts them into the database `table orders` in to columns `band_id` and `user_id`.

This is not happing I am just getting my or die `("could not add to database");` string come up.

Is there a problem with the way I have done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name=\"band\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"". $Band_id."\" >
```

And you're trying to get POST variable "Band_id" (which does not exist)

```
$Band_id = $_REQUEST['Band_id'];
```

Should be

```
$Band_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['band']);
```

Other details:

1. In order.php, it's better to place "session_start()" at the
   beginning (before anything)
2. Consider using mysqli or PDO instead of deprecated mysql
3. You could get band id with $_POST instead of $_REQUEST because your
   form sends it with post method

Comment: Let's see the error with that: or die ("could not add to database: " .mysql_error());

Comment: Nope, my bad small spelling mistake. thank you very much for the advise.